# JMeter. How to determine when thread group is finished

Tags: jmeter, threadgroup

I need two separate thread groups to be run(Second group have infinite loop count). And when the first group is done stop the second one. How can I determine when the first group is done?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's work for me:

- Crete "BeanShell PreProcessor" with this code:
  `props.put("DONE", "FALSE");`
- Create "BeanShell PostProcessor" with this code:
  `int activeThreadCount = org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterContextService.getNumberOfThreads();
  if (activeThreadCount <= 1)
  {
  props.put("DONE", "TRUE");
  }`

Add If Controller with:
`${__BeanShell( props.get("DONE") != null && props.get("DONE")=="TRUE")}`

Stop Current Thread inside If Controller.

Answer (score 1):

You can attach a post-processor to the first threadgroup, which sets a flag value in a property.

Your second threadgroup will contain a loop until the property contains the flag value you are waiting for.

Comment: Yes I was thinking about it but all post-processors is executed after each sample not after thred group is done

Comment: You can attach the post-processor to the thread group, and it will execute after all samplers. or you can attach it to the last sample in the group.

Comment: How can I attach to thread group post-processor? Help said that all  pre/post processors executed before/after sample. You can check it by putting BeanShell PostProcessor with line `log.info("Run post-processing");`

Comment: right click thread group->add->post-processors->beanshell post-processor. this will run after the thread group

Comment: No. It will run after each sampler.

Comment: correct, after cheking this, it does.. you can attach it to the last sampler in the thread group, or create a beanshell sampler. I was trying to avoid creating an extra sample..

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following solution:

**Thread Group 1**
      Beanshell Sampler - props.put("finish", "FALSE");
      HTTP1
      HTTP2
      ....
      Beanshell Sampler - props.put("finish", "TRUE");

**Thread Group 2**
      While Controller  - ${__BeanShell( props.get("finish") != null || props.get("finish")=="TRUE" )}
            HTTP1
            HTTP2
            ....

Hope this will help.

Comment: No it doesn't fit my needs. If we have iterations in Thread Group 1 than we will have problems in Thread Group 2