# If Controller of jMeter throws StackOverflowError

Tags: jmeter, threadgroup

I am using jMeter to load my system.
I have two Thread Groups. The first one should inject about 1M events, while the second one mimic requests to UI.

I need the second thread group to continue sending request to the UI, until the first one finishes injecting the 1M events.

I have found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26465338/jmeter-how-to-determine-when-thread-group-is-finished) solution, and implemented it as follows:

1. In the first thread group, I have added BeanShell PreProcessor with the following code:

   > props.put("DONE", "FALSE");
2. Still in the first thread group, I have added BeanShell PostProcessor with the following code:

   > int activeThreadCount =
   >   org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterContextService.getNumberOfThreads();
   >
   > ```
   > if (activeThreadCount <= 1)
   > {
   > props.put("DONE", "TRUE");
   > }
   > ```
3. In the second thread group I have added an If Controller with the following condition:

   > ${__BeanShell( props.get("DONE") != null &&
   >   props.get("DONE")=="TRUE")}

This solution is not working and I see the following error at the end of the test:

> 2016/12/22 20:52:30 ERROR - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Test failed!
>   java.lang.StackOverflowError  at java.lang.String.valueOf(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.apache.jmeter.engine.util.CompoundVariable.execute(CompoundVariable.java:152)
>     at
>   org.apache.jmeter.engine.util.CompoundVariable.execute(CompoundVariable.java:117)
>     at
>   org.apache.jmeter.testelement.property.FunctionProperty.getStringValue(FunctionProperty.java:101)
>     at
>   org.apache.jmeter.testelement.AbstractTestElement.getPropertyAsString(AbstractTestElement.java:271)
>     at
>   org.apache.jmeter.control.IfController.getCondition(IfController.java:177)
>     at org.apache.jmeter.control.IfController.next(IfController.java:240)
>     at
>   org.apache.jmeter.control.GenericController.nextIsAController(GenericController.java:222)
>     at
>   org.apache.jmeter.control.GenericController.next(GenericController.java:176)
>     at
>   org.apache.jmeter.control.LoopController.next(LoopController.java:123)
>     at
>   org.apache.jmeter.control.GenericController.nextIsAController(GenericController.java:225)
>     at
>   org.apache.jmeter.control.GenericController.next(GenericController.java:176)
>     at
>   org.apache.jmeter.control.LoopController.next(LoopController.java:123)
>     at
>   org.apache.jmeter.control.LoopController.nextIsNull(LoopController.java:151)
>     at
>   org.apache.jmeter.control.GenericController.next(GenericController.java:171)
>     at
>   org.apache.jmeter.control.LoopController.next(LoopController.java:123)
>
> ......
>
> ......
>
> ......
>
> (Continue for about 1000 line as above)

Can any one tell me what is the source of this error?
Can I simply ignore it?
It looks like it is a recursive operation without any stop condition.

Thanks
Guy H

Answer (score 2):

This could be an old bug in JMeter < 2.12 if the If Controller is the only child of LoopController and it is false on start.

There has been some fixes in recent versions of JMeter:

- https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=56160

Try with new versions of JMeter

The workaround is to add as first child of Loop Controller a [Test Action](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Action) (renamed to Flow Control Action since 5.0) with pause = 0

Comment: This fixed the same problem for me, except I did not have a LoopController, just an IfController. Added the suggested Flow Control Action directly above my IfController and the bug was avoided.